# About taking limit of an integral on Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, wolfram-alpha-queries

I tried computing this quantity on Wolfram Alpha, but I couldn't get any answer:

```
Series [ (I*x + y*exp(I*p))*(tanh (pi*(I*x + y*exp(I*p))) )*(log ((
I*x +  y*exp(I*p) )^2 + a^2))*(I*y*exp(I*p)), {y,0,2}, {Assuming
x>0,y>0,a>0, p real}]
```

If I understand Mathematica correctly, it is evaluating

$$lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} [ \int _{\phi = -\pi} ^{\pi} z\text{ }tanh(\pi z) log(z^2 + a^2) dz] \text{ for }z = i(n+\frac{1}{2}) + \epsilon e^{i\phi} = (1+2n)log[a^2 - (n +\frac{1}{2})^2]$$

Am I using Mathematica correctly?

Comment: Not in the slightest. Your syntax is nothing close to *Mathematica*'s: should be e.g. `Exp[x]`, `Pi`, `Assumptions -> {x>0, y>0, Element[p, Reals], ...}`. What does your question have to do with Wolfram|Alpha, by the way? We are not well positioned to answer W|A questions at this site because we are just users, and W|A's input interpretation is usually highly arbitrary and inconsistent with *Mathematica*, understood only by WRI (if at all).

Comment: Please see my comment to your answer below!

Answer (score 5):

Your input should be:

```
Series[
 (I x + y Exp[I p]) Tanh[Pi (I x + y Exp[I p])]
 Log[(I x + y Exp[I*p])^2 + a^2] I y Exp[I p], 
 {y, 0, 2}, 
 Assumptions -> {x > 0, y > 0, a > 0, p ∈ Reals}
]
```

Asterisks can be used for multiplication, but a space is more usual. I removed unnecessary parentheses. The more important points are

- all functions (`Exp`, `Log`, `Tanh` etc.) and other built-in symbols start with a capital letter
- function application is always done using brackets, not parentheses (and it is considered quite unusual style to insert a space between the name of a function and its bracketed arguments, although it is not an error to do so)
- `Assumptions` is an option of `Series`, and options are given as rules, not lists. `Assuming` is not an option name; rather it is the name of a function.
- `p real` is a multiplication. To specify that `p` is real you should have `Element[p, Reals]` or its infix form, `p \[Element] Reals`

With the corrected input, an answer is produced quickly by *Mathematica*. However, when this is given to Wolfram|Alpha, it chokes horribly, interpreting it as "Series Exp Tanh", and a completely nonsensical answer (relating to stock prices) is produced. It just goes to show that W|A cannot be used as a substitute for *Mathematica*, and unfortunately, if prior experience is any guide, there is probably no way to persuade W|A to interpret the input as you intend.

---

The result is:

```
SeriesData[y, 0, {
  (-I)*E^(I*p)*x*Log[a^2 - x^2]*Tan[Pi*x], 
  -(E^((2*I)*p)*Pi*x*Log[a^2 - x^2]) + 
  (2*E^((2*I)*p)*x^2*Tan[Pi*x])/(a^2 - x^2) -
  E^((2*I)*p)*Log[a^2 - x^2]*Tan[Pi*x] -
  E^((2*I)*p)*Pi*x*Log[a^2 - x^2]*Tan[Pi*x]^2
 }, 1, 3, 1
]
```

Comment: Yes, if I had typed this in Mathematica then I would have typed as you wrote above. I though Alpha could interprete what I wrote! Can you kindly type in the answer for this or for the integral that you see on Mathematica?

Comment: @user6818 I added the result. I don't believe that `Series` involves any integration; only differentiation. See its documentation, which states it produces a Taylor series.

Comment: Thanks for the effort (1) This "SeriesData" format looks unfamiliar to me. It should have produced a  Taylor series. How do I see that in the format you wriote it? (2) By "integral" I wanted to know what Mathematica gives as output for the limit of an integral that I wrote in the question.